# Confusion about determinant properties for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Consider a $3 \times 3$ matrix
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> a & b & c\\ 
> d & e & f \\
> g & h & i\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> Assume that we know $\det(A)=\frac{1}{2}$. Calculate $$\det\begin{bmatrix}
> 3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
> d-a & e-b & f-c \\
> g-2d & h-2e & i-2f\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

---

I attempted the following:

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d-a & e-b & f-c \\
g-2d & h-2e & i-2f\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d & e & f \\
g-2d & h-2e & i-2f\\
\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
-a & -b & -c \\
g-2d & h-2e & i-2f\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

The second determinant is $0$ since the 1st and 2nd row are scalar multiples of each other. So now we have:

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d & e & f \\
g-2d & h-2e & i-2f\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d & e & f \\
g & h & i\\
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d & e & f \\
-2d & -2e & -2f\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

The second determinant is $0$ since the 2nd and 3rd row are scalar multiples of each other. So now we have:

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d & e & f \\
g-2d & h-2e & i-2f\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
3a & 3b & 3c\\ 
d & e & f \\
g & h & i\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Is this just $$\det(A)=3\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
d & e & f \\
g & h & i\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\det(A)=3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)?$$

Or is it $$\det(A)=3^3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)?$$

I feel like it's the 1st one but I am not sure. Can someone clarify this last step?

Comment: It is the first one. If you multiply all the elements of the matrix by $3$ the determinant would be multiplied by $3^{3}$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Consider the identity matrix and what happens if one element is multiplied by $3$, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result:
in an $ n×n$ matrix  $A$  , if a row  (column)  be multiplied by a scalar c then $det A$ is multiplied by c
So your first result is true.